# Which Y level should I build my glass roof on to prevent lightning from hitting my house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I read somewhere that lightning spawns at Y level 127, however I cannot verify it or find the source anymore. If I was to build my glass roof on Y level 256, would this be enough to stop my house from getting hit by lightning? Or should I build it on level 126?

Comment: Where did you read it from? If you can remember, please include a link.

Comment: Why not try it in a seperate Creative Mode world?